# right dockpanel

Tags: xaml, tabcontrol, dockpanel

i a newbie in xaml and i need your help about tabcontrol
i want to make a tab control with tab panel or dock panel in right..
if we follow this :

```
<TabControl>
 <TabItem Header="first" />
 <TabItem Header="Second" />
</TabControl>
```

will automatically create left top dockpanel or tabpanel, how to make itu top right..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but have you tried setting the TabStripPlacement property?

```
 <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Right">
    <TabItem Header="first" />          
    ...
```